# Console indicates i'm running operations on a closed file even though I used the "with open" command

Tags: python, xml-parsing, biopython

I'm struggling with this.
I'm trying to write a small report of the XML file above, yet when I run the code it notifies an error starting from when I input my print commands, stating that I'm using these operations on a closed file.
My code seems correctly indented, so I don't know what's wrong... thank you for your help

```
#parsing the results

with open("mirna_blast.xml","r") as file_handle:

    blast_record_list=NCBIXML.parse(file_handle)
    #using parse since there are 6 sequences in the file

    #for loop as parsing returns an ITERATOR
    for blast_record in blast_record_list:
        print("\tQuery description : ",blast_record.query)
        print("\tQuery length : ",blast_record.query_length)
        print("\tQuery ID : ",blast_record.query_id)
```

Comment: Did you try ```print(blast_record_list)```? Does it return something

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: are you sure you have the same indentations in ful code?

Comment: This code works for me if I use it on a test file in biopython: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/tree/master/Tests/Blast/xml_2212L_blastp_001.xml 

The error you see may come from using `file_handle` outside (after) the with statement.